# Maximum digits allowed after decimal in double datatype in vb6

Tags: vb6, double

I want to know how many number of digits are allowed after decimal point for primitive double datatype in vb6, without actually getting rounded off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get up to 16 significant figures in case of double data type in vb6 with accuracy

eg `1.0000000000000006`

Comment: You're only going to get 15 digits (total -- not just places). Try 0.1234567890123456 as a counterexample. (BTW, 1.0000000000000006 would round to 1.0000000000000007 if VB actually let you display it to that many digits)